# Borland C++ - Build Without Runtime Packages from Command Line

Tags: c++builder, borland-c++

Does anyone know how to build without runtime packages in Borland C++ with the command line?

On their builder, I know you got to Options->Packages and uncheck "Build with runtime packages", but I don't see how to replicate this from the command line.

Thank you

Comment: When you build in the IDE it shows you the commandline used for build, just copy-paste that.  To see what difference the checkbox makes, copy-paste the commandline with and without the checkbox and compare the results.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I didn't know the IDE showed that.

Comment: It depends on which version you are using.  Modern version do, older versions do not.  You did not say which version you are using.